# Статьи по программированию на английском

Tags: документация, перевод

Можете посоветовать какие-нибудь хорошие статьи на английском по программированию или индивидуально по каким-то языкам. Нужно для перевода.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Моя любимая](http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/), правда перевод на русский уже где-то был, да и терминология там не самая адовая.